# Configure the label of Active Admin has_many

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, activeadmin, formbuilder

Well I have a two models related with a on-to-many assoc.

```
#models/outline.rb
    class Outline < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :documents
    end

#models/document.rb
    class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :outline
    end

#admin/outlines.rb
    ActiveAdmin.register Outline do
      form do |f|
        f.inputs "Details" do
          f.input :name, :required => true
          f.input :pages, :required => true
          ...
          f.buttons
        end
        f.inputs "Document Versions" do 
          f.has_many :documents, :name => "Document Versions"  do |d|
            d.input :file, :as => :file
            d.buttons do
              d.commit_button :title => "Add new Document Version"
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

Well as you can see in the admin/outlines.rb I already tried setting up the :name, in the has_many :documents, and the :title in the commit_button, but neither of that options work, I also tried with :legend, :title, and :label, instead of :name in the .has_many. Not working.

This is the result of that code:
[Screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/696/screenshotoyt.png)

What I want to display is "Document Versions" instead of "Documents", and "Add new Document Version" instead of "Add new Document"

If someone can have a solution it would be great

Comment: I have the same issue, I posted it in the issue tracker. Perhaps you can add more information to it: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/786

Comment: It seems you can't: `form_buffers.last << template.content_tag(:h3, association.to_s.titlecase)` (from active admin form_builder.rb)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To set `has_many` header you can use

```
f.has_many :images, heading: 'My images' do |i|
  i.input :src, label: false
end
```

See [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb#L70)

Answer (score 6):

Looking at [ActiveAdmin tests](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/spec/unit/form_builder_spec.rb)("should translate the association name in header"), there may be another way of doing this. Use your translation file.

If you look at [ActiveAdmin has_many method](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb) (yuck!!! 46 lines of sequential code), it uses [ActiveModel's human method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/75d58fef26bcd52cf5c814466836c4b527a6547c/activemodel/lib/active_model/naming.rb#L45).

Try adding this to your translation file

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      document:
        one: Document Version
        other: Document Versions
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to deal with changing the name of a class in your forms. Have all my upvotes.

Comment: How is this not the top answer? It's so so so simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

One quick hack is that you can hide the h3 tag through its style.

**assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss**

```
    .has_many {
      h3 {
        display: none;
      }}
```

This will hide any h3 tag under a has_many class.

Answer (score 4):

You can customise the label of the "Add..." button by using the `new_record` setting on `has_many`. For the heading label you can use `heading`:

```
f.has_many :documents,
           heading: "Document Versions",
           new_record: "Add new Document Version" do |d|
  d.input :file, :as => :file
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Sjors answer is actually a perfect start to solving the question. I monkeypatched Active Admin in config/initializers/active_admin.rb with the following:

```
module ActiveAdmin
 class FormBuilder < ::Formtastic::FormBuilder
  def titled_has_many(association, options = {}, &block)
   options = { :for => association }.merge(options)
   options[:class] ||= ""
   options[:class] << "inputs has_many_fields"

   # Set the Header
   header = options[:header] || association.to_s

   # Add Delete Links
   form_block = proc do |has_many_form|
     block.call(has_many_form) + if has_many_form.object.new_record?
                                  template.content_tag :li do
                                    template.link_to I18n.t('active_admin.has_many_delete'), "#", :onclick => "$(this).closest('.has_many_fields').remove(); return false;", :class => "button"
                                  end
                                else
                                end
  end

  content = with_new_form_buffer do
    template.content_tag :div, :class => "has_many #{association}" do
      form_buffers.last << template.content_tag(:h3, header.titlecase) #using header
      inputs options, &form_block

      # Capture the ADD JS
      js = with_new_form_buffer do
        inputs_for_nested_attributes  :for => [association, object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new],
                                      :class => "inputs has_many_fields",
                                      :for_options => {
                                        :child_index => "NEW_RECORD"
                                      }, &form_block
      end

      js = template.escape_javascript(js)
      js = template.link_to I18n.t('active_admin.has_many_new', :model => association.to_s.singularize.titlecase), "#", :onclick => "$(this).before('#{js}'.replace(/NEW_RECORD/g, new Date().getTime())); return false;", :class => "button"

      form_buffers.last << js.html_safe
    end
  end
  form_buffers.last << content.html_safe
  end
 end
end
```

Now in my admin file I call titled_has_many just like has_many but I pass in :header to override the use of the Association as the h3 tag.

```
f.titled_has_many :association, header: "Display this as the H3" do |app_f|
  #stuff here
end
```

Comment: thanks dude! If I will get some time, I will try to apply that fix to active_admin repo

Comment: but there is another issue here - we can't rename "Add more Resources" button :/

Answer (score 0):

Does not deserve a prize but you could put this in config/initializers/active_admin.rb . It will allow you to tweak the headers you want using a config/locales/your_file.yml (you should create the custom_translations entry yourself). Dont forget to restart the server. And use the f.hacked_has_many in your form builder.

```
module ActiveAdmin
  class FormBuilder < ::Formtastic::FormBuilder
    def hacked_has_many(association, options = {}, &block)
      options = { :for => association }.merge(options)
      options[:class] ||= ""
      options[:class] << "inputs has_many_fields"
      # Add Delete Links
      form_block = proc do |has_many_form|
        block.call(has_many_form) + if has_many_form.object.new_record?
                                      template.content_tag :li do
                                        template.link_to I18n.t('active_admin.has_many_delete'), "#", :onclick => "$(this).closest('.has_many_fields').remove(); return false;", :class => "button"
                                      end
                                    else
                                    end
      end
      content = with_new_form_buffer do
        template.content_tag :div, :class => "has_many #{association}" do         

          # form_buffers.last << template.content_tag(:h3, association.to_s.titlecase)
          # CHANGED INTO
          form_buffers.last << template.content_tag(:h3, I18n.t('custom_translations.'+association.to_s))

          inputs options, &form_block

          # Capture the ADD JS
          js = with_new_form_buffer do
            inputs_for_nested_attributes  :for => [association, object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new],
                                          :class => "inputs has_many_fields",
                                          :for_options => {
                                            :child_index => "NEW_RECORD"
                                          }, &form_block
          end
          js = template.escape_javascript(js)
          _model = 'activerecord.models.' + association.to_s.singularize
          _translated_model = I18n.t(_model)
          js = template.link_to I18n.t('active_admin.has_many_new', :model => _translated_model), "#", :onclick => "$(this).before('#{js}'.replace(/NEW_RECORD/g, new Date().getTime())); return false;", :class => "button"

          form_buffers.last << js.html_safe
        end
      end
      form_buffers.last << content.html_safe
    end
  end
end
```

If you have issues with locale files not being loaded good in staging/production mode, adding this to your application.rb might help (substitute :nl for the right locale)

```
config.before_configuration do
  I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config','locales','*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  I18n.locale = :nl
  I18n.default_locale = :nl
  config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config','locales','*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
  config.i18n.locale = :nl
  config.i18n.default_locale = :nl
  I18n.reload!
  config.i18n.reload!
end
config.i18n.locale = :nl
config.i18n.default_locale = :nl
```