# Customize ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder (make different partial)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I want to use ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder, because I like the way it allows to generate nested models (mostly - its `has_many` method, which generates nice buttons with inline javascript to easily create & destroy nested objects).

However I want to edit form itself, because the way it looks by default takes too much space.

Does anyone know if there's a good way to customize the form design output, but keep those nested  methods for nested objects?

Here is a code example with comments:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @item, builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f| %>

    <% f.inputs "Item Details" do %>
      <% f.input :keywords %>
      <% f.input :description %>
    <% end %>

    <% f.inputs "Features", :id => "item_features" do %>
      <% f.has_many :features, :header => "" do |feature| %>
        <!-- all these fields are generated in separate rows, I want to fit them all to one row - so need to add some classes-->
        <% feature.input :name, :label => "Feature Name" %>
        <% feature.input :value, :label => "Feature Value" %>
        <% feature.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label=>'Remove Feature' %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <% f.inputs "Options", :id => "item_options" do %>
      <% f.has_many :options, :header => "" do |option| %>
        <!-- same thing here -->
        <% option.input :name, :label => "Option Name" %>
        <% option.input :_destroy, :as=>:boolean, :required => false, :label=>'Remove Option' %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>

    <% f.actions %> <!-- here I want to add some classes to each button -->
  <% end %>
```

Comment: I believe if you are using the `ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder`, `f.has_many` should available to your form (https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/9f6b03030667801adc58af4aba9ae56160c3b0b2/lib/active_admin/form_builder.rb#L44). Does your code above not work? If not, what errors are you seeing?

Comment: Code above works. I just don't like the design it generates. So far my best idea was to copy FormBuilder module and manually make required changes.

Comment: Perhaps all you need is better CSS rules?

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: the problem with CSS is that it's more difficult than simple table, and I have no idea how it will work in different browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of researches - I made most obvious changes using CSS.

For deeper changes I found this post: [Configure the label of Active Admin has_many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310997/configure-the-label-of-active-admin-has-many)

Also thinking, maybe will use JavaScript to do some changes on page load.